# console.log(array) returns filled array, but console.log(array.length) is 0?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm having trouble with an array and I cannot find what exactly is the problem.

First a function executes the following two lines in a loop:

```
varArray[overlapCounter] = [a, b, c];
overlapCounter++;
```

If I run `console.log(varArray)`, the chrome log gives me the following:

```
[]
```

By opening the brackets this is the contents:

```
Array[0]
0: Array[6]
1: Array[6]
2: Array[6]
3: Array[6]
4: Array[6]
5: Array[6]
6: Array[6]
7: Array[6]
8: Array[6]
9: Array[6]
10: Array[6]
11: Array[6]
12: Array[6]
13: Array[6]
14: Array[6]
15: Array[6]
16: Array[6]
17: Array[6]
18: Array[6]
19: Array[6]
20: Array[6]
21: Array[6]
22: Array[6]
23: Array[6]
24: Array[6]
25: Array[6]
26: Array[6]
27: Array[6]
28: Array[6]
29: Array[6]
30: Array[6]
length: 31
__proto__: Array[0]
```

But if I run `console.log(varArray.length)`, the value is `0`, and `console.log(varArray[0])` returns `undefined`.

Does anyone know what is going on there?

### Full code:

```
$('#Salvar').click(function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          var dt_inicio_afastamento = $('#dt_inicio_afastamento').val();
          var dt_fim_afastamento = $('#dt_fim_afastamento').val();
          var observ_afastamento = $('#observ_afastamento').val();
          var id_ocorrencia = $('#id_ocorrencia').val();
          if ( dt_inicio_afastamento === "" || dt_fim_afastamento === "" || id_ocorrencia === ""){
            return swal({
                    title: 'Todos os campos são obrigatórios!', 
                    type: 'warning'
                });
          }
          else{
            function ajax2(names, dt_inicio_afastamento, dt_fim_afastamento, id_docente, observ_afastamento, id_ocorrencia){  
              $.ajax({
                url: '../engine/controllers/afastamento.php',
                data: {
                  id_afastamento  : null,
                  dt_inicio_afastamento : dt_inicio_afastamento,
                  dt_fim_afastamento : dt_fim_afastamento,
                  observ_afastamento : observ_afastamento,
                  id_ocorrencia : id_ocorrencia,
                  id_docente : id_docente,
                  action: 'create'
                },
                error: function() {
                  swal({ 
                      title: 'Erro na conexão com o servidor',
                      text :'Tente novamente em alguns segundos',
                      type: 'error'
                  });
                },
                success: function(data) {
                  //console.log(data);
                  if(data === 'true'){
                    names.css( "background-color", "lightgreen" );
                  }
                  else{
                   names.css( "background-color", "lightcoral" );
                  }
                }, //Sucesso Ajax2
                type: 'POST'
              }); //Ajax2
            }
            var overlapCounter = 0;
            var varArray = [];
            var requests = [];
            $(".cada_docente").each(function(index) {
              var names = $(this).prev();
              var id_docente = $(this).val();
              var nomeSerie = names.children('.nomeSerie').text();
              var requests = Array();
              (function(names, nomeSerie, dt_inicio_afastamento, dt_fim_afastamento, id_docente, observ_afastamento, id_ocorrencia){
                requests.push($.ajax({
                  url: '../engine/controllers/afastamento.php',
                  type: 'POST',
                  data: {
                    id_afastamento  : null,
                    dt_inicio_afastamento : dt_inicio_afastamento,
                    dt_fim_afastamento : dt_fim_afastamento,
                    observ_afastamento : observ_afastamento,
                    id_ocorrencia : id_ocorrencia,
                    id_docente : id_docente,
                    action: 'overlap'
                  },
                  success: function(data) {
                    if (data == "true"){ajax2(names, dt_inicio_afastamento, dt_fim_afastamento, id_docente, observ_afastamento, id_ocorrencia);}
                    else{
                        varArray[overlapCounter] = [names, dt_inicio_afastamento, dt_fim_afastamento, id_docente, observ_afastamento, id_ocorrencia];
                        overlapCounter++;
                    } 
                  } //Sucesso Ajax1
                })); //Ajax1
              })(names, nomeSerie, dt_inicio_afastamento, dt_fim_afastamento, id_docente, observ_afastamento, id_ocorrencia); //Ajax1 Função
            }); // Cada Docente
            var defer = $.when.apply($, requests);
            defer.done(function(){
                console.log(varArray);
                });


          } //Else dados colocados
        });
```

Comment: Please show the code in context. Is it asynchronous? When you log an object (including arrays), the console keeps a live reference to the object, so even if it was empty at the moment it was logged, by the time you click on it it may have been populated. The `.length`, however, is logged as it was at the time.

Comment: Could you please post the full code here?

Comment: the full code of the function is a monster right now, but alright, i'll post it:

Comment: can you do `console.log(varArray, varArray.length);` and tell what it logs?

Comment: console.log(varArray, varArray.length); returns [] 0. when opened, there are many arrays inside the [].

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your problem is that `console.log` is not guaranteed to be synchronous; for object references like arrays, when you view the object's property tree you are seeing the tree ***as it is currently*** rather than ***as it was when you called `log`***. Integers, on the other hand, are passed by value and thus when you `log(array.length)` you get the value of the length at the very instant `log` was called.

If you want to print the array as it as when you called `log`, you should first make a copy of it using `array.slice()` (note that this only creates a shallow copy of the array):

```
console.log(array.slice())
```

Comment: The fact that it is inside a 

defer.done(function(){
       console.log(varArray);
});

doesnt change this behaviour?

Comment: No, it does not. You will have to use `array.slice()` as I suggested above if you want to take a snapshot of the object structure at that instant.

Comment: console.log(varArray.slice()); logs even less than before :/
Now its just an empty array with length 0, before it was logging all the arrays inside as well.

Comment: So what are you trying to log? The updated value of the `length` property? You will have to view that inside the array reference when you print it.

Comment: the log is just the start, I want to actually use the values inside of varArray, but I can't get the length, or the individual arrays inside varArray, apart form logging the entire thing, javascript returns anything I try to do as undefined...

Comment: That means your array hasn't been filled by the time your `log` statement is called. You mentioned you were doing this inside of a `Deferred`; I would suggest posting that entire code as a new question and trying to find out why it is not working as intended.

Comment: Alright, I did post the entire code in this question but its quite huge...

Comment: Please post this as a **new question**, since this question has been marked as a duplicate already.