# How to get array index values in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Hi I can't get the value of a specific index of an array. I don't know why because if I try to log the entire array it works but with a specific index it doesn't work

This is my code, I use cloud firestore to get the ID of a document and save it into array

```
var idUsers = [];
const users_list = document.querySelector("#users_list");

db.collection("utenti").get().then(function(querySnapshot) {

    querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
        users_list.innerHTML += "<a href='utente.html' class='collection-item black-text'>" + doc.data().nome + " " + doc.data().cognome + " " + " </a>";
        idUsers.push(doc.id);
      });
});

console.log(idUsers);
console.log(idUsers[0]);
```

This is the result in Chrome console
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JnnMS.png)

Comment: see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42991854/console-logarray-returns-filled-array-but-console-logarray-length-is-0

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Although it is considered to be a confusing statement, I assume that the operation is running **asynchronously**. Try to put a delay and then find value of `idUsers[0]` in order to find out the assumption.